# how extract last part of paths given by specific condition

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract last part of directories from specific `date=20220110` and having construction like :

```
/rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/20220104-020124/file1.txt
/rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/20220105-020113/file2.txt
/rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/20220111-020124/file3.txt
/rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/20220112-420123/file4.txt

 ...
```

**NOTE** :
Please note that paths are located in **HDFS** repository. In other world, we should run :

```
hdfs dfs -ls /rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/*
```

to get the list of archive names.

As you can see we have many date here `20220104` , `20220105` , `20220111` and `20220112`

In other world I should develop a loop operator that take all path which exists in hdfs :

```
/rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/
```

and return a list having values like : `20220111-020124` and `20220112-420123` because `20220111` and `20220112` are dates given after `20220110`

Any help please ? Thank you

Comment: isn't there a problem with `202201013` and `202201014`? what format is that?

Comment: @Fravadona, there are string format and we can consider the date variable as `date=20220110`

Comment: Why is it that some entries have a dash in the time stamp, and some don't?

Comment: @user1934428, sorry it was an error, I correct it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler approach is to use `awk`. Simply split the last field of each record on `'-'` and compare against `20220110`:

```sh
$ ls -1 /rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/* |
awk -F'/' '{split($NF, a, "-"); if (a[1]>20220110) print $NF}'
```

(**note:** above is `ls -(one)` not `ls -(el)`)

You can tailor the search for files further by using `find` instead of `ls`. Up to you.

Result:

```
202201013-020124
202201014-020123
```

You can further sort or split as needed.

Comment: Hello @David C. Rankin, what if the `/rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/*` what if this path is located in hdfs ?

Comment: You can't have a file named `'*'` in Linux shell. Is that what you are asking? Otherwise if you are asking what if the names is `some_file.ext` -- then it simply will fail the range expression comparison and won't be printed.

Comment: I tested your command like this `hdfs dfs -ls -d /rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/* | awk -F'/' '{split($NF, a, "-"); if (a[1]>20220110) print $NF}'` because `/rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/*` is a path in HDFS having many files. But it return empty string.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You can have a file named `*` (or `'*'` if single quotes are literal). Try `touch '*' "'*'"`. And what characters a filename can have is not a shell issue.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thank you, but it return files which are located in `/rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/20220104-020124/`, for example. I do not need that, I need just to extract the `20220104-020124` value

Comment: Okay, then use `ls -1d /rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/*/` and you will only retrieve the directory names. Pipe the results to `awk` as shown. The fact they are directories and not files wasn't clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the month and day fields always contain preceding `0`,
would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

refdate='20220110'

for f in /rec/flux_entrant/le5/archive/tble91_formation/*; do
    base=${f##*/}
    if [[ $base =~ ^([0-9]{4})(0[1-9]|01[0-2])(0[1-9]|0[1-3][0-9])- ]]; then
        if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]: -2}${BASH_REMATCH[3]: -2} > $refdate ]]; then
            echo "$base"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
202201013-020124
202201014-020123
```

- The regex `^([0-9]{4})(0[1-9]|01[0-2])(0[1-9]|0[1-3][0-9])-` will match the
  formatted date, assigning the bash array `BASH_REMATCH` to the matched
  year, month, and day.
- The expression `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]: -2}${BASH_REMATCH[3]: -2}` reformats the array values into the date string as `yyyy-mm-dd`.
- Then the date string is compared with the reference date `20220110`.

If the month is between October and December and the string is
formatted as 202201001 (1st of October, 2022), it will also work.

Comment: hello @tshiono, please look to the edited question, the referenced date for comparaison has the `YYYYMMDD` and not `YYYY-MM-DD`, please look to the edit question

Comment: @SA2018 Your comments show that you didn't even **bother** to try to understand what the code in the answers does...

Comment: @SA2018 I have modified my code according to your edit. I'd say you are encouraged to test the answers *before* you change the question.

Comment: thank you @tshiono, but sorry it does not work, `javaSetEnv : distrib java utilisee /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk
./RA_1090.ksh: line 542: syntax error at line 546: `~(E)^([0-9]{4})(0[1-9]|01[0-2])(0[1-9]|0[1-3][0-9])- ]]; then`